# How to pass parameter to constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

Basically my code is as follows.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the coursebook");
            String cousebookname = Console.ReadLine();
            Person p1 = new Person(String cousebookname);
            p1.displayMessage();
        }
    }
}
public class Person
{
    private String courseName;
    Person(String name)
    {
        courseName = name;
    }
    public void displayMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The name of the course is \n{0}", courseName);
    }

}
```

I have created Person class and defined courseName as private variable, constructor and method. In the main class, I have created created instance of Person object.As per my understanding, as soon as instance is created, the constructor is initialized. When I pass parameter String coursebookname, error occurs saying "the name cousebookname doesnot exist in current context". Please help.

Comment: You can only define the `coursebookname` variable one time (which is when you specify the type). Remove the `String` designation from before the variable name when you pass it to the `Person` constructor and it should work fine.

Comment: `Person p1 = new Person(cousebookname);` Spelling aside.

Comment: The reason for that error is your class Person is present out of the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some adjustments:

```
    Person p1 = new Person(cousebookname);
```

Pass the variable name only.

```
public Person(String name)
    {
        courseName = name;
    }
```

Make the constructor public.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
Person p1 = new Person(cousebookname);
```

Comment: still the error persists

Comment: 'Person.Person(string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @pallavidestiny22 How about making the constructor _public_ then?

Comment: yeah it worked then thanks